# AES 128 Compatibility between android and Objective C

Tags: java, android, ios, encryption, aes

I have two applications: Android and iOS (Objective-C). And I'm trying to implement and encryption system so I can encrypt on both apps and decrypt in a server application. The problem is that I'm using AES128-ECB but the base64 key that I'm getting from android does not match with my objective c key. I have no idea what I'm missing.

Here are the snippets:
IOS

```
- (NSData*) EncryptAES: (NSString *) key{
char keyPtr[kCCKeySizeAES128+1];
bzero( keyPtr, sizeof(keyPtr) );

[key getCString: keyPtr maxLength: sizeof(keyPtr) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
size_t numBytesEncrypted = 0;

NSUInteger dataLength = [self length];

size_t bufferSize = dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128;
void *buffer = malloc(bufferSize);
const unsigned char iv[] = {0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00};

CCCryptorStatus result = CCCrypt( kCCEncrypt,
                                 kCCAlgorithmAES128,
                                 kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
                                 keyPtr,
                                 kCCKeySizeAES128,
                                 iv,
                                 [self bytes], [self length],
                                 buffer, bufferSize,
                                 &numBytesEncrypted );

if( result == kCCSuccess )
    return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:numBytesEncrypted];
else {
    NSLog(@"Failed AES");
}
return nil;
}
```

And then:

```
NSString *pass = @"WORD_TO_ENCRYPT";
NSString *key = @"STRING_KEY";

//Encryption - APPROACH 1
NSData *data = [pass dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSData *encryptedData = [data EncryptAES:key];
NSString* encryptedBase64 = [self Base64Encode:encryptedData];

NSLog(@"%@", encryptedBase64);
```

This is my Java function:

```
    String plainTextKey = "STRING_KEY";
    String plainText = "WORD_TO_ENCRYPT";
    // Encrypt where jo is input, and query is output and ENCRPYTION_KEy is key
    //String inputtt = "some clear text data";
    byte[] input = new byte[0];
    String skyKey;

    input = plainText.getBytes("utf-8");
    MessageDigest md;
    md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
    byte[] thedigest = md.digest(plainTextKey.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    SecretKeySpec skc = new SecretKeySpec(thedigest, "AES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skc);
    byte[] cipherText = new byte[cipher.getOutputSize(input.length)];
    int ctLength = cipher.update(input, 0, input.length, cipherText, 0);
    ctLength += cipher.doFinal(cipherText, ctLength);
    String encode = Base64.encode(cipherText);
    System.out.println(encode);
```

I'm banging my head against the wall without knowing what I'm missing.
Thanks in advance for your help!

PS: I don't have any particular reason to use AES128-ECB. I can use any other algorithm if the multi system compatibility is simpler.

Comment: Why don't you just use RNCryptor then? It has the necessary compatibility and is more secure than this code.

Comment: It doesn't look to me that you're using ECB mode in Obj-C. You should change the Java code to CBC mode.

Comment: General advice: **Always use a fully qualified Cipher string.** `Cipher.getInstance("AES");` may result in different ciphers depending on the default security provider. It most likely results in `"AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding"`, but it doesn't have to be. If it changes, you'll lose compatibility between different JVMs.

Comment: **Never use [ECB mode](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/14487/13022)**. It's deterministic and therefore not semantically secure. You should at the very least use a randomized mode like [CBC](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/22260/13022) or [CTR](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/2378/13022). It is better to authenticate your ciphertexts so that attacks like a [padding oracle attack](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/18185/13022) are not possible. This can be done with authenticated modes like GCM or EAX, or with an [encrypt-then-MAC](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/202/13022) scheme.

Comment: Is the encryption successful, and the results are different between iOS and Android? Or the encryption failed? Please provide with more details.

Comment: Another side note, if you don't have an iv, you can just put 0 instead of putting a char array.

Answer (score 0):

On the Android side, when you initialize the Cipher instance, you must provide the matching IV.

```
byte[] iv = {0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00};
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skc, new IvParameterSpec(iv));
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using an hardcoded IV for the encryption mechanism, at least on Android. The usage of  **Random Number Generators** is advised, but if you can not provide a random value, at least build the IV from the key.

On the other hand, you won't have good security if everything is derived from the password; **you need some randomness in every message.**

Make sure to store the IV used during the encryption so you can properly apply it back on the decryption.

```
byte[] iv = {0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00};
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skc, new IvParameterSpec(iv));
```